# Unable to load classes/modules with Zeitwerk on Ruby project

Tags: ruby, autoload, zeitwerk

I have built a Ruby project and I want to switch from using a ton of `require_relative` statements to a smarter autoloader like [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk).

There are a lot of files/folders in the project, hence I will only present some of them in order to not make my question too bloated with unnecessary details. You can find the whole project on [Github](https://github.com/Uaitt/chess/tree/temp).

The structure of the repo is the following

```
chess/
  bin/
    chess
  lib/ 
    chess.rb
    chess/
      board.rb 
      serialize.rb
      coordinates.rb 
      pieces/
      (other files and folders)
  (other files)
```

`bin/chess` is the executable file and contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "zeitwerk"

loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
loader.setup

Chess.new.start  # method that starts the whole game
```

`lib/chess.rb` contains the `class Chess`, which runs the logic of the game.

All the other files inside of `lib/` follow the [Zeitwerk file structure](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#file-structure).

Therefore, `lib/chess/serialize.rb` contains

```
class Chess 
  module Serialize 
    ... 
  end 
end
```

and `lib/chess/pieces/piece.rb` contains

```
class Chess 
  module Pieces 
    module Piece 
    ... 
    end 
  end 
end
```

When I try to run the script, with `bin/chess` (or `cd`ing into the `bin/` folder and running `./chess`), the terminal returns

```
uninitialized constant Chess (NameError)
```

It seems like the files are not loaded by Zeitwerk. I read all of their documentation but I was not able to discover what's the problem.

edit:
As one of the answers pointed out, I removed the `for_gem` call in `bin/chess` with

```
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
loader.tag = File.basename(__FILE__, ".rb")
loader.inflector = Zeitwerk::GemInflector.new(__FILE__)
loader.push_dir("#{__dir__}/../lib")
loader.setup
```

However, now all the classes/modules inside of the `Chess` namespace are loaded, while all the ones located in deeper directories, like `lib/chess/display/chess_display.rb` (which is `Chess::Display::ChessDisplay`) don't get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Readme, `for_gem` corresponds to:

```rb
# lib/my_gem.rb

require "zeitwerk"
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
loader.tag = File.basename(__FILE__, ".rb")
loader.inflector = Zeitwerk::GemInflector.new(__FILE__)
loader.push_dir(__dir__)
```

note the `push_dir(__dir__)` and that it's expected to be called from the `lib/` directory.  You're calling it from a file in the `bin/` directory.

I have not used zeitwork like this, but I think you might want to either:

1. directly require just `lib/chess.rb` and perform the `Zeitwork::Loader.for_gem` in that file
2. Skip `for_gem` and use the snippet above, but adjust `__dir`__ to be `../lib`.

Comment: I have adjusted that snippet with `loader.push_dir("#{__dir__}/../lib/")`, 
however now I get the error
`uninitialized constant Chess::ChessDisplay (NameError)`.


Basically the modules located at `lib/chess` got loaded, while all the ones located in a nested directory like `lib/chess/display/` did not got loaed.

Comment: I have also tried the first approach you proposed, but I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

You use `for_gem` in `lib/chess.rb`. That way, the setup is ready no matter how you load the library.

The `bin/chess` executable then loads the entry point. It should not issue a `require_relative`, but a regular `require 'chess'` assuming `lib` is in the load path.

Same for the test suite, just `require 'chess'` in the test or spec helper that sets the test suite up.

Comment: I have followed your advice. However, I still get `uninitialized constant` errors. 

As an example, my `lib/chess.rb` file contains
`class Chess  include ChessDisplay`.
`ChessDisplay` is located at `lib/chess/display/chess_display.rb` and contains 

`class Chess module Display module ChessDisplay`.

Am I doing something wrong with namespacing? It feels like all the files located at `lib/chess` are located, but the ones located in nested directories, like `lib/chess/display` don't get loaded.

Comment: Cool. The file `lib/chess/display/chess_display.rb` should define the constant `Chess::Display::ChessDisplay`, and it seems to be correct according to the contents you described (the nested class and modules are fine, they are really defining that constant). However, the `include` should be of `Display::ChessDisplay`, not `ChessDisplay`. Because the existing `include` is looking for some `Chess::ChessDisplay` that does not exist, see?